# is there a way to use page id = to load more than 1 page?

Tags: wordpress, loops

Evening,

is there a way to use $page id = to load more than 1 page?

ie:

```
    $page_id = 2;

$page_data = get_page( $page_id );
```

Or am I coming about this the wrong way?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

`get_page()` is deprecated, use `get_post()` instead.

ids are unique, and wouldn't be much use if they weren't! If you have an array of posts you can load them with a foreach

```
$page_ids = array( 1, 2, 3, 4 );

$pagess = array();

foreach( $page_ids as $page_id ) {
    $pages[] = get_post( $page_id );
}
```

You now have `$pages` as an array of WP_Post objects.

Comment: I don't believe this is what he is asking.  I think he was referring to pages.  I could be wrong though.

Comment: get_posts will return a page if the id passed is for a page. Pages are a wordpress post type.

Comment: That makes sense.  Never really thought of it like that.

Comment: Ideally I want to pull in two page page, the second on has a little content but it makes sense to separate them in the back end. Thanks all.

Comment: You can just do `$page_one = get_post( $page_one_id );` `$page_two = get_post( $page_two_id );` and then use the information loaded in whatever way you want. You have [WP_Post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post) objects.

Answer (score 0):

If by "load more than one page" you mean display the content from more than one page to a single page of the site, then yes you can do it.  Here's a way you could do it.

```
<?php
    $my_postid = 114; // This is page id or post id
    $content_post = get_post($my_postid);
    $content = $content_post->post_content;
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
    $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);
    echo $content;
?>
```

You could repeat this block as many times as you would like, as long as you change the ID number in the first line.  Hopefully this is what you are asking for, I wasn't sure I understood the question fully.